# What is the quality of Fotga filters?

Tags: filters, image-quality, color-correction, accessories

I am looking for a cheap beginner filter kit. I came across Fotga in ebay, but I could not find more information about the manufacturer on the internet. Do you know about them? Is the quality ok?

Answer (score 1):

I have a set of ND (2/4/8) and Polarizing filters from Fotga. The quality is not superb, but they do the job ;) And for the price point I think they are pretty good, definitely a good buy for a beginning.

I have made some tests, comparing pictures without any filters and with Fotga ND and Polarizer filters just to compare whether they are degrading the quality and just by looking at the pictures (even at 100%) there are no visible differences in sharpness. Off course if you make a lab test, shooting chart board and comparing pixel by pixel the difference will be there, but in real life situations there is not much of a difference.

But on the other hand ND filters tent to produce slightly bluish cast, but nothing too extreme, easy to fix in editing software.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. : ) Is your CPL filter coated, or not? Could you send me some pictures? I found only 2-3 short videos in youtube but nothing about the manufacturer, thats why i asked : )

Comment: Mine is not multi coated, I payed like 6$ for it some 7 years ago. I will search for sample pictures a bit later.

Comment: @KirilMladenov, actually I checked my filter and they are not Fotga, they are Green-L, which is cheaper than Fotga.